# Restore database with a FileTable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore, filetable

We have a SQL Server 2014 (build 12.0.24457.0) database with two tables in, both are FileStream tables, the biggest has 2979466 rows, `SUM(cached_file_size)= 40564905472`.

We have tried to restore this database on to our test server, but it takes quite a long time. Our DBA gave up after 14 days.

Has anyone else tried to restore a database with FileStream tables, with more that a few files in?

I'm running this script to monitor the progress:

```
BEGIN TRY
    DROP TABLE #h 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

DECLARE @r INT=1, @percent_complete NUMERIC(9,2), @Extimated_Completion_Datetime DATETIME2(0)
CREATE TABLE #h ( start_time DATETIME2(0), percent_complete NUMERIC(9,2), Estimated_completion_time NUMERIC(9,2), HoursSinceStart NUMERIC(9,2), Extimated_Completion_Datetime DATETIME2(0), session_id INT, created_date datetime2(0))
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(19) , @e VARCHAR(max)


WHILE @r > 0 BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO #h
    SELECT start_time, percent_complete, CAST(ROUND(estimated_completion_time/3600000.0,1) AS DECIMAL(9,1)) AS Estimated_completion_time
    , CAST(ROUND(total_elapsed_time/3600000.0,1) AS DECIMAL(9,1)) AS HoursSinceStart
    , DATEADD(HOUR, CAST(ROUND(estimated_completion_time/3600000.0,1) AS DECIMAL(9,1)), GETDATE()) AS Extimated_Completion_Datetime
    , session_id
    , GETDATE()
    FROM
    sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
    WHERE
    r.session_id <> @@SPID
    AND r.session_id > 50
    AND command LIKE 'restore database'
    SELECT @r = @@ROWCOUNT

    select top 1 @percent_complete=percent_complete, @Extimated_Completion_Datetime=Extimated_Completion_Datetime from  #h ORDER BY created_date DESC
    SET @d = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), @Extimated_Completion_Datetime, 121) 
    SET @e = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 121) + ' we are ' + LTRIM(@percent_complete) + '% complete. We estimate to finish at: ' + @d
    RAISERROR('At %s ', 10, 1, @e) WITH NOWAIT


    --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00'
END
```

So far I've this outcome:

```
At 2016-06-08 10:35:46 we are 00.01% complete.
At 2016-06-08 14:22:46 we are 39.26% complete. We estimate to finish at: 2016-06-08 18:22:47
At 2016-06-08 14:23:46 we are 39.27% complete. We estimate to finish at: 2016-06-08 18:23:47
At 2016-06-08 14:24:46 we are 39.28% complete. We estimate to finish at: 2016-06-08 18:24:47
...
At 2016-06-09 08:33:07 we are 44.80% complete. We estimate to finish at: 2016-06-10 09:33:08
At 2016-06-09 08:34:07 we are 44.80% complete. We estimate to finish at: 2016-06-10 09:34:08
At 2016-06-09 08:35:07 we are 44.80% complete. We estimate to finish at: 2016-06-10 09:35:08
At 2016-06-09 08:36:07 we are 44.81% complete. We estimate to finish at: 2016-06-10 09:36:08
At 2016-06-09 08:37:07 we are 44.81% complete. We estimate to finish at: 2016-06-10 09:37:08
At 2016-06-09 08:38:07 we are 44.81% complete. We estimate to finish at: 2016-06-10 09:38:08
At 2016-06-09 08:39:07 we are 44.82% complete. We estimate to finish at: 2016-06-10 09:39:08
...
At 2016-06-10 08:12:01 we are 47.86% complete. We estimate to finish at: 2016-06-12 08:12:02 
At 2016-06-10 08:13:01 we are 47.86% complete. We estimate to finish at: 2016-06-12 08:13:02
```

Not exactly fast. It has managed to go from 42% to 45% in 13:45, so with the current speed it looks to finish at 2016-06-27 13:45, or in 18 days. For 44 GB!

```
SELECT top 10000 resource_description AS resource_description, * 
FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
WHERE session_id=64
```

says:

> wait_type=`BACKUPTHREAD`

...sometimes `BACKUPIO` too

So I've set up another restore to get Restore Messages:

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604, 3605, 3014);
RESTORE DATABASE [VDCFileStreamhespotest] FROM  DISK = N'\\dkrdsvdcp19\MSSQL_Backup\Full\Misc\VDCFileStream_backup_2016_06_07_180004_7123139.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 1
, move 'VDCFileStream'      to 'P:\MSSQL\DPA\System\MSSQL10_50.DPA\MSSQL\DATA\UserDBs\VDCFileStream\VDCFileStreamDBhespo.mdf'
, MOVE 'VDCFileStream_log'  to 'P:\MSSQL\DPA\Log\Log02\VDCFileStream\VDCFileStreamDBhespo_log.ldf'
, MOVE 'VDCFileStreamF1'    to 'G:\VDCFileStream\FileStreamDatahespo'
```

```
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): RESTORE DATABASE started
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): Opening the backup set
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): Processing the leading metadata
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): Planning begins
Backup/Restore buffer configuration parameters
Memory limit:               32767 MB
BufferCount:                6
Sets Of Buffers:            2
MaxTransferSize:            1024 KB
Min MaxTransferSize:        1024 KB
Total buffer space:         12 MB
Tabular data device count:  1
Fulltext data device count: 0
Filestream device count:    1
TXF device count:           0
Filesystem i/o alignment:   512
Media Buffer count:         6
Media Buffer size:          1024 KB
Encode Buffer count:        6
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): Effective options: Checksum=1, Compression=1, Encryption=0, BufferCount=6, MaxTransferSize=1024 KB
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): Planning is complete
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): Beginning OFFLINE restore
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): Attached database as DB_ID=48
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): Preparing containers
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): Containers are ready
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): Restoring the backup set
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): Estimated total size to transfer = 45540792320 bytes
Restore(VDCFileStreamhespotest): Transferring data
1 percent processed.
```

Here 5 days later we're now over halfway there:[image: but the rest of the journey is going to be long]

Comment: @Kin; Instant file init is on. Power plan set to High perf. I've just checked it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to restore a 45GB database with 32GB memory on the server.

What you can do is bump up the memory (RAM) on the server and play with

1. Stripe your backup to multiple LUNs or disk.
2. Use [`BUFFERCOUNT`, `BLOCKSIZE`, `MAXTRANSFERSIZE`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82505/8783) backup parameters along with `INIT` & `COMPRESSION` (you are using it as I see from your output) to tune your backup.
3. Dont use CHECKSUM while taking backup since it can contribute to a longer backup time. Instead try restoring the backup to a different server to test it - this will confirm that you are able to restore it and then run CHECKDB to confirm there is no corruption.

As of now, you are only getting 6MB which is pretty low.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**
I've finally managed to get the database restored.
It took only 124 minutes, when we changed some settings on the server.

I found the settings here: https://support.microsoft.com/da-dk/kb/2160002

and here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778996.aspx

In case the links stops working:
in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem 
NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate and NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation should be set to 1