# SQL Server Backups in Parallel

Tags: backup, sql-server-2016, ola-hallengren

Currently I am using ola hallengren  backup and maintenance scripts.

I have a question:

I have 5 big databases in one server. It's taking approximate 10+ hours everyday to complete full backups. Currently it's writing in sequentially into disk.

I want to write all backups parallel to reduce time. Is there any way I can write backups parallel?

I am taking compressed and verify only backups to network location

Comment: Define "Big"?  Honestly, your best and easiest way to faster full backups will be to write to multiple files. specify the Number Of Files option when taking the backup using Ola's scripts.  To actually run in parallel, just create multiple jobs to run at the same time and specify the database names.

Comment: see if [my answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82505/8783) helps you. You can use powershell to perform backups in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

Create additional jobs to run backups in parallel.  Make sure to specify a single unique database per job.  Configure the SQL Server Agent jobs to start the backup at approximately same time, with a 1 minute delay between each job.

You may find that running backup jobs simultaneously does not significantly decrease backup time.  You should evaluate the I/O capability of the disks where the databases reside, the disks where the backups are being written to, and in the case of network backups, the capacity of the network to transfer data.

Comment: thanks for above input, I created additional jobs to run backups in parallel. but one of the DB taking 10:30 hours total backup time. but backup size is 349 GB, please suggest me how to reduce backup time

Comment: 349Gb is the compressed backup size Right? Are you backing it up to local disk or UNC path? Are the I/O on the backup device fast? Last thing you should try is definitely split up the files like Ven suggested.

Comment: Yes, this is a compressed backup. I am using network share location to save backup files, I am using ola hallengren scripts for backup solution, I am not sure how to use Ola scripts to split backups files

Comment: Have you looked at option D in this link ? https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html . Be sure to test it out on a test environment first. Maybe try splitting to 10 files first?

Comment: yes I did that, now all big backups completing within time, thank you very much for your quick response

Comment: Awesome! Do you mind sharing how many files you split into and how long did it take the complete a backup?

Comment: I did for 10 files, it took1 hour to complete backup. thanks to all